# Sending multiple sms in quick succession using Twilio

Tags: python, django, ssl-certificate, twilio, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to send sms using twilio and django 1.8.2. I am facing a problem when there are multiple calls to send sms within the same function.

This is the code snippet to send an sms to any particular phone number:

```
def send_twilio_message(to_number, body):
    client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(
        settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    return client.messages.create(
        body=body,
        to=to_number,
        from_=settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER
    )
```

When I make two requests to this function like this:

```
def some_function():
    send_twilio_message(number1, "text 1")
    send_twilio_message(number2, "text 2")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/dreamhost/CCBT/trial_IITK/views.py" 
in waitlist_phq
  782.             exclusion_code = waitlist_alert(wl.participant, 
phq_score)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/dreamhost/CCBT/trial_IITK/views.py" 
in waitlist_alert
  857.             send_twilio_message(phonenumber, 'Looks like your 
child maybe having suicidal thoughts. Get in touch with your child 
ASAP. - TreadWill.')
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/dreamhost/CCBT/sendsms/utils.py" in 
send_twilio_message
  13.         from_=settings.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py" in create
  122. return self.create_instance(kwargs)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py" in create_instance
  365. data=transform_params(body))
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py" in request
  200. resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, 
**kwargs)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py" in make_twilio_request
  152. resp = make_request(method, uri, **kwargs)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py" in make_request
  117. resp, content = http.request(url, method, headers=headers, 
body=data)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in request
  1314. (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, 
request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in _request
  1064. (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri,         
method, body, headers)
File "/home/arka/Project/TreadWill/env/lib/python3.5/site-    
packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in _conn_request
  987. conn.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py" in connect
  1260. server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  377. _context=self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py" in __init__
  752. self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py" in do_handshake
  988. self._sslobj.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py" in do_handshake
  633. self._sslobj.do_handshake()

Exception Type: SSLError at     
/iitk/phq/NnBLRUEsbm5jbERmfGZWNkt6RVNPcEFBNnplNkA4RVFOTkN4TnI=/
Exception Value: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

But, when I do this:

```
import time
def some_function():
    send_twilio_message(number1, "text 1")
    time.sleep(60)
    send_twilio_message(number2, "text 2")
```

it is working fine. The problem with this approach is that the user might close the browser if the page keeps loading for 60 seconds (I've tried for less than 60 seconds, I get the same error).

I've tried disabling SSL verification in my Twilio account, but that didn't work.

I've looked into other answers, and I've gone through Twilio's documentation. I haven't been able to figure out a good solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
I was trying all this on my localserver. When I tried the code:

```
def some_function():
    send_twilio_message(number1, "text 1")
    send_twilio_message(number2, "text 2")
```

on a hosted server, it worked fine. So, I think the problem might be due to my institute's network. The problem is resolved for me, but I still haven't been able to figure out why I was facing the issue. If anyone has any idea why this might be happening, please post your answer.